# Python regex: How to match a number with a non-number?

Tags: python, regex

I want split number with another character.

**Example**

Input:

```
we spend 100year
```

Output:

```
we speed 100 year
```

Input:

```
today i'm200 pound
```

Output

```
today i'm 200 pound
```

Input:

```
he maybe have212cm
```

Output:

```
he maybe have 212 cm
```

I tried `re.sub(r'(?<=\S)\d', ' \d', string)` and `re.sub(r'\d(?=\S)', '\d ', string)`, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
ins='''\
we spend 100year
today i'm200 pound
he maybe have212cm'''

for line in ins.splitlines():
    line=re.sub(r'\s*(\d+)\s*',r' \1 ', line)
    print line
```

Prints:

```
we spend 100 year
today i'm 200 pound
he maybe have 212 cm
```

Same syntax for multiple matches in the same line of text:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s*(\d+)\s*',r' \1 ', "we spend 100year + today i'm200 pound")
"we spend 100 year + today i'm 200 pound"
```

The capturing groups (generally) are numbered left to right and the `\number` refers to each numbered group in the match:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)',r'\2\3\1','567')
'675'
```

If it is easier to read, you can name your capturing groups rather than using the `\1 \2` notation:

```
>>> line="we spend 100year today i'm200 pound"
>>> re.sub(r'\s*(?P<nums>\d+)\s*',r' \g<nums> ',line)
"we spend 100 year today i'm 200 pound"
```

Comment: d'oh!  Why didn't I think of that.  +1

Comment: Yes. Several things to note. The `r` at the beginning of the regex strings changes the meaning of the '\' in those strings so that they are easier to read. The capturing group parenthesis are numbered (generally) left to right. So if you had `re.sub(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)',r'\2\3\1','123')` it will print `231' Just practice a few and you will get it.

Answer (score 2):

This takes care of one case:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])(?=\d)',r'\1 ',s)
'he maybe have 212cm'
```

And this takes care of the other:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)([a-zA-Z])',r' \1',s)
'he maybe have212 cm'
```

Hopefully someone with more regex experience than me can figure out how to combine them ...

Comment: i use both. and work now!
can you explain why that work??
why \1 work?
THANK YOU!

Comment: @NamNamNam -- `'\1'` matches expands to the result of the first capturing group it encounters.  Likewise, `\2` would be the second group, etc. etc.

Comment: @NamNamNam -- Sure, no problem.  I've re-tagged your question with `regex` to hopefully involve that community a bit more.  I'm still betting someone gives a better answer than this one.